# Problem with connecting to SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDb in Visual Studio 2019 on 32 bit system

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a C# project using VS 2019 which connects to LocalDb.

Any machine which has 64 bit, I install SQL Server 2016 LocalDb before running my project and after that it works fine.

Now some machines are using 32 bit operating system, so I installed SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

But my project is not working and I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "A network or specific instance error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server could not be found or is unavailable. Make sure the instance name is correct and that remote connections are allowed on SQL Server. (Provider : SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - A Local Database Runtime error occurred. An unexpected error occurred while calling the LocalDB instance API method. For more information about the error, see the Windows Application Event Log.

This is my connection string:

```
Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\TestDB.mdf
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I believe, with SQL Server **2012**, LocalDB was using a different "default" instance name. Try running `sqllocaldb info` on one of your 32-bit machines - what does it list out? If I'm not mistaken, it used to be something like `(localdb)\v11` or something. If that's the case - just adapt your connection string on those 32-bit machines accordingly

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for your response. After installing MS 2012 Express LocalDb on 32 bit machine, I run sqllocaldb info but it is giving error "SqlLocalDb is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: The `sqllocaldb` tool is installed on your machine - for SQL Server 2012 in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn` directory. You might need to either switch to that directory, or add it to your path, in order to run `sqllocaldb`

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I will follow that on client machine and inform to you. Thanks again.

Comment: SQL Server requires the mdf file to be on a drive physically mounted on the same machine as the server.  The d: driver cannot be a network drive on another machine.

Comment: @jdweng, for database, I am using project current path and put mdf file there. thanks

Comment: Where is the Net Library located.  The SQLClient library is the server and should be on same machine as the mdf file.  You can use the d:\ drive if it mounted on the machine as the Net Library.

Comment: @marc_s, After changing my connection string to "V11" instead of "MSSQLLocalDB", it is giving version "The database cannot be opened because it is version 852. this server supports version 782".

Comment: You cannot just move the `.mdf` file from a newer SQL Server version (2016) to an older version - that is not supported. You will need to build the SQL Server database for your LocalDb 2012  version from SQL scripts.